# DHCP Server shutting down?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failover, dhcp-server, essentials-2012-r2

I have a Server 2012 R2 Essentials server, which is the PDC in the domain.  I also have another 2012 R2 server acting as a domain controller for times when the primary is down.

I have setup DHCP on the secondary server as a hot standby.  Both servers are communicating fine, and I can see changes at one DHCP server reflected in the other.

From time to time though, the DHCP server on the Essentials server shuts down, and I see this in the system log:

`The DHCP/BINL service on this Small Business Server has encountered another
server on this network with IP Address A.B.C.D, belonging to the
domain: .`

The IP listed is the server acting as a hot standby.  `.` is not the name of the domain though.

What is causing the DHCP service on the Essentials server to shutdown, and how do I correct it?  Perhaps I mis-configured the fail over somehow?

Comment: I have read several posts about that behaviour. It's the SBS/Essentials DHCP server rogue detection which is not working correctly with failover servers as it assumes to be the only DHCP. You can disable the rogue detection in your registry if you are sure about your config, otherwise there seems to be no fix other than stopping your failover server, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, one of the rules when using essentials is that you can have no other DC's in the domain. I think the rule goes even further to say you can have no other servers in the domain.

Comment: @larryc no, that's wrong. You are allowed to have other dcs as long as the essentials server holds the fmso roles, the same as it was with sbs.